Do MSR / MRS Aarch64 instructions have an intrinsic for VS C++?
I know that reading/writing to Intel MSRs have an intrinsic for the VS C++ compiler. I'm wondering if reading/writing to Aarch64 system registers also has an intrinsic for Visual Studio.

You only need to scroll up a little to the ARM64 intrinsics list. TL;DR: yes _ReadStatusReg and _WriteStatusReg

@Jester I saw it, but is it any system register, or just the status register?

Must be any because it takes the register as an argument.

@Jester hmm, thanks. That documentation is less than ideal. Let me play with it to figure out how can I specify an Aarch64 system register as an int.

For example, _ReadStatusReg(2) generates mrs x8,OSDTRRX_EL1. Not sure if the register names are exposed somehow. intrin.h does not seem to have them. Maybe search the include directory in case there is a header with the symbolic names.

@Jester oh ok, found it. It needs the ARM64_SYSREG(op0, op1, crn, crm, op2) macro from winnt.h to generate an int for those intrinsics. Then the op0, op1, crn, crm, op2 parameters come from the Arm documentation for a specific system register.
